# Can google app engine cron jobs trigger a background cloud function?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

After read the docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml

It seems that `cron jobs` only support `HTTP` cloud function.

I want to use `GAE` `cron jobs` and `google pubsub` to trigger my background cloud function every hour. Like:

`GAE corn jobs` => `Cloud pub/sub` => background `cloud function`.

Is this possible?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include Cloud Scheduler, which can be also helpful.

Comment: @Mangu thanks a lot. I built this system successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't **directly** call Cloud Functions from a Cron job, as it's an [App Engine service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml), but you can call an App Engine handler from your Cron job, and make that handler call your Cloud Function, using whichever information you want to use from Pub/Sub.

There is an example [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-functions-scheduling-cron-5657c2ae5212), which is basically what I said. You can substitute it to use Node.js in App Engine instead of Python:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const request = require('request');

  request('YOUR_FUNCTION_URL', { json: false }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    res
      .status(200)
      .send('Trigger called')
      .end();
  });
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
```

**EDIT**:

[Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) is a new service (as of right now in beta) which can create cron jobs that target either App Engine, Pub/Sub or URL's. In your case, you can set up one job hitting the URL of your function, as mentioned [in here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating). It's much simpler.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing I am not sure. Google docs recommend using this architecture: `GAE` Cron service => `GAE` Cron server => `GCE` util => `GCF`. For now, I don't use `GCE`. I put util in `GAE` and the system works fine. Should I use `GCE`?

Comment: And, I think you should use `cloud pub-sub` to trigger background `cloud function`, should not use `request` module

Answer (score 0):

The Cron service is not integrated with cloud functions. It is part of app engine.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and is described in detail [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/functions-cron).